# Fixing routing mechanism for ng2 app on a server

Tags: angular, routes

I have built an ng2 app with routing mechanism. While routing is working great on my `localhost`, the routing mechanism works partially on a real server. How should I point out that `index.html` on a real server in the root directory is the router? Can anyone explain is it `.htaccess` and how to create it correctly or at least point out reference material on how to create `.htaccess` with ng2 files?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us some code, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it inside of .htaccess it'll point all urls to index.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: You are right ... I fix it eventually my self with htacces . thank you very much